# Почему — огульно?

Tags: этимология

"Огульно" — значит, напрасно, безосновательно. Интересно бы узнать происхождение этого слова. При чем тут "гулять"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Огульно - это не совсем безосновательно, это значит на общих основаниях, не делая различий. *Петя ранее был уличён в воровстве яблок. Кто-то неизвестный украл яблоки. Обвинение Пети в хищении, только на основании этих фактов, было бы огульным. А скажем, обвинить в пропаже Барака Обаму, поступком было бы уже не огульным, а именно безосновательным.*

Огул - это все вместе, совокупность, скоп. Гулом (огулом) также по Далю может означать оптом.

Так что в данном случае, "огульно" и "гулять" вряд ли друг с другом связаны.